# API 3.8: After dragging a marker, if marker.setMap(null) then it doesn't appear more

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using version v3.8 I got this behaviour with dragged markers.

a) marker.setMap(map)   --> Marker on map

b) dragg the marker     --> It's a dragged marker

c) marker.setMap(null)  --> hiding the marker

d) marker.setMap(map)   --> The marker doesn't appear

If I force use v=3.7, everything works ok, in d) the marker appears in the map.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following QAH's comment this does appear to be a bug in Version 3.8. See [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4052) and add your star to it to help get it fixed.

A workaround is to use `marker.setVisible(false)` or an earlier version, as you found.

Comment: But notice here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#RemovingOverlays It says that passing null to setMap() just removes them from the map. If you want to actually delete the overlay, you will have to set a null reference to it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will use setVisible, it works and allows me use the v3.8 for working with the weather library.